# fetch the data from table and display it the gridview in yii 2.0

Tags: php, arrays, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a controller in that i have wrote a function to get the values from the table. and im passing it to the dataprovider.

```
 public function actionBorrower()
{

   $user = User::find()->all();

   $dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider([
    'user' => $user,
    'pagination' => false,
    ]);

    return $this->render('borrower', [
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);
}
```

Now in the view file i want to display it in the Grid-view, The table in the database has many users i want to fetch all of them and display it one by one.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

$this->title = 'Users';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<section style="margin-top:60px;display:inline-block;height:640px;width:100%;padding:15px 0 0 15px;" class="wrapper">
<div class="user-role-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'user_id',
            //'role_id',


            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
</section>
```

I dont no where im going wrong, But some errors are coming up like -  **Setting unknown property: yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::user**

I’m new to yii2, kindly any one help me to solve this.. Thank you.

**I want to fetch all data from USER Table where the user_type is "1" in USER_TYPE Table.. Two tables are involved in this. How do i write this query in above??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your definition activedataprovider to:

```
$dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => User::find(),
    'pagination' => false,
]);
```

Or if you want to get all `user` before create dataprovider, you should use `ArrayDataProvider`

```
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => User::find()->all(),
    'pagination' => false,
]);
```

Refer to document: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html

Goodluck and have fun!

Comment: Deleting my answer as it says the same thing here :) !

Comment: Thanks. Goodluck and have fun :)

Comment: I want to fetch all data from USER Table where the user_type is "1" in USER_TYPE Table..  How do i write this query in above??

Comment: May be it like that:
`User::find()->with('user_type')->where(['user_type.id' => 1])->all()`.

`user_type` is attribute in USER table, and `id` is define type in USER_TYPE table.

Hope it helpful.